# List HBA information on Solaris 11 OS

Tags: solaris, storage, san

Actually I want to know how can I see the Luns presented using a HBA WWN.

The view that I want is something like this:

LUN (on the server side like /dev/rdsk/...) | WWN (from the server) | Paths (the paths that connect my hba wwn from the server to the hba's wwn of the storage)

Comment: Do you use any 3rd-party multipathing software (EMC, Veritas, etc)?

Comment: No. I do not have any 3rd party software installed on my OS. I just have a Hitachi HUS 130 and Sun Storage 6580.

Answer (score 1):

`fcinfo` may give the information you require.

Example:

```
# fcinfo remote-port -s -p 10000000c993b528
Remote Port WWN: 5006016239a01db6
        Active FC4 Types: SCSI
        SCSI Target: yes
        Node WWN: 50060160b9a01db6
        LUN: 0
          Vendor: DGC
          Product: LUNZ
          OS Device Name: /dev/rdsk/c2t5006016239A01DB6d0s2
        LUN: 1
          Vendor: DGC
          Product: RAID 5
          OS Device Name: /dev/rdsk/c3t60060160545D1C00C0369BCD3361DC11d0s2
[etc]
```

More examples at https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-identify-the-hba-cardsports-and-wwn-in-solaris/

Comment: Ummm. I see. What is the differences on HBA Port WWN and Node WWN?, by the way.

Comment: In storage systems, the system itself has one Node WWN for the entire system and one Port WWN for each FC port it has. In add-on cards, the manufacturer cannot know whether the system already has a Node WWN or not, so each add-on FC card typically has its own Node WWN. If there are multiple add-on HBAs in a server, the FC card drivers have to decide how to represent the "entire system" to the FC network. But as far as I know, usually the Port WWN is the more important one.

Comment: Ummm. So, zoning on SAN environment, just is needed the HBA WWN and not the node WWN, right?.

Comment: This seems to be descending into a whole set of new questions.

Answer (score 1):

discover all HBAs using

```
fcinfo hba-port
```

to filter wwid

```
fcinfo hba-port | awk '/HBA Port WWN/ { print $4 ; } ' | while read wwid
do
  echo fcinfo remote-port -sl -p $wwid
  fcinfo remote-port -sl -p $wwid
done
```

that will give you which equipement is connected to your local HBA.

to configure switch zone use `Remote Port WWN:` field. (please note you can only see this information after zoning)

In my case local and remote HBA are

```
## local
HBA Port WWN: 2100001b329ca67b
        Node WWN: 2000001b329ca67b
HBA Port WWN: 2101001b32bca67b
        Node WWN: 2001001b32bca67b
HBA Port WWN: 2100001b329b4169
        Node WWN: 2000001b329b4169
HBA Port WWN: 2101001b32bb4169
        Node WWN: 2001001b32bb4169

## disk (HUS)
Remote Port WWN: 50060e80103efe51
        Node WWN: 50060e80103efe51
Remote Port WWN: 50060e80103efe59
        Node WWN: 50060e80103efe59

## Tape
Remote Port WWN: 500104f000cd769d
        Node WWN: 500104f000cd769c
Remote Port WWN: 500104f000cd76a3
        Node WWN: 500104f000cd76a2
Remote Port WWN: 500104f000cd768b
        Node WWN: 500104f000cd768a
Remote Port WWN: 500104f000cd7691
        Node WWN: 500104f000cd7690

## disk
Remote Port WWN: 50060e80103efe50
        Node WWN: 50060e80103efe50
Remote Port WWN: 50060e80103efe58
        Node WWN: 50060e80103efe58

### tape
Remote Port WWN: 500104f000cd769a
        Node WWN: 500104f000cd7699
Remote Port WWN: 500104f000cd76a0
        Node WWN: 500104f000cd769f
Remote Port WWN: 500104f000cd7688
        Node WWN: 500104f000cd7687
Remote Port WWN: 500104f000cd768e
        Node WWN: 500104f000cd768d
```

note that port and node are different, port is used for zoning.